# Interpreting this headline: "Split 7 Ways, Immigrant Neighborhood Seeks to Unify Its Political "

Tags: headlinese

The Headline is:

> Split 7 Ways, Immigrant Neighborhood Seeks to Unify Its Political Power ([source](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/11/10/nyregion/redistricting-queens-asians-nyc.html))

I can't figure out "Split 7 Ways" is it a reference to something locally  known OR a variation to that reference?

Answer (score 7):

The usage "split [a number] ways" [means](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/split-something-two-three-etc-ways) "split into [that many parts]."

Even knowing that, the meaning of the headline overall is not immediately obvious (as is often true with headlines); I had to check the article to find exactly what it's referring to.

The article is about a neighborhood that feels like one whole, where political maps have divided it into seven different regions that vote separately for government positions.

Comment: one question though: when you say "that vote separately for elected representatives." did you mean: "that vote separately for electing representatives."?? I mean you vote for electing representative right? if they are elected they don't need vote right?

Comment: @EulerHenriquePintoAraujoVa Thanks; I edited to be more clear. (For one thing, not all elected leaders are "representatives"; a secretary of agriculture doesn't "represent" constituents in a legislative body.) But yes, I meant "vote for" to mean "vote [to elect]." (And sure, in some cases an already-elected official might still be running as an "incumbent" to be re-elected.)